# vw golf chico 1.3 1998 model wont start after replacing starter

Tags: vw

Please pardon me as i am not good with cars as most guys would be. I have a problem with my vw golf chico 1,3 catched fire on a starter while i was trying to start it this morning. Later today i went to buy and replaced the starter. I adviced one of the auto electrician of my problem and suggested that when i fit the starter i should not connect the ignition cable/wire to the starter(as my ignition would not push back after turning and starting the engine before, i would do it manually). Okay then i do as he asked me to do just to get the engine started by bridging the starter with a wire from a positive terminal of the battery to the starter. The starter tries to turn on an engine but its just not enough to start it i have a 2weeks old 646 12v battery that i just bought and yet tested using my multimeter which read 12.35at the as i hv been trying to start the car several time bridging it but just doesnt want to start. I had the car serviced a month ago. I tried to kick start the car but still unlucky i am worrued what could this be...not sure if anything got damaged in the process when old starter caught fire. Or maybe whether a new starter just isnt quality and i cant return it as it is an electronical thing. Your help and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Loose battery connections can cause low current.

Comment: You need to edit and improve your question - I don't understand what you are doing with ignition wires and how they "push back"...